# Showing that a function is an isometry of the complex plane and showing that a composition of functions in the complex plane is a translation

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

a). Let $a ∈ \Bbb{C}$ be fixed. Show that the map $T_a : \Bbb C → \Bbb C$ given by $T_a(z) = z + a$ is an isometry of
$\Bbb C$. This is a translation of the complex plane $\Bbb C$.

For this first one, I think that I need to show that:

$d(T_a (z), T_a (u)) = z+a - (u +a) = z-u = d(z, u)$. So this is an isometry.

b). Let $f, g : \Bbb C → \Bbb C$ be given by $f(z) = (1+i)z+(1−i)$ and $g(z) = −iz$. Show that $f ◦g◦f^{−1} ◦g^{−1}$ is a translation of $\Bbb C$.

For this, I have that $f^{-1}(z) = \frac {z-(1-i)}{1+i}$ and $g^{-1}(z) = \frac{-z}{i}$. Then taking $f ◦g◦f^{−1} ◦g^{−1}(z) = 2-z$. I think I did something wrong here. This doesn't look like a translation. It looks like a reflection and a translation.

Any help solving these would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think its just a calculation mistake which you have done. Just check it out. It comes out to be $2+z$ which is a translation.